# UPSERT in PGSQL (version 11,)does the unique constraint be maintained always?

Tags: postgresql, upsert

For `ON CONFLICT(col)` clause in **UPSERT**, should there be **unique** constraint for the column or combination of columns.
for eg:
if I have a simple table `create table test(id integer ,name  text )`,Will I not be able to do UPSERT ?the UNIQUENESS constraint have to be enforced ?
Please help as I am confused.

Answer (score 0):

A unique constraint must be fulfilled at the end of a transaction. So it can't become non-unique - you would get an error and the transaction would be rolled back. [UPSERT](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/sql-insert.html#SQL-ON-CONFLICT) can't fail:

> ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE guarantees an atomic INSERT or UPDATE outcome;
> provided there is no independent error, one of those two outcomes is
> guaranteed, even under high concurrency. This is also known as UPSERT
> — “UPDATE or INSERT”.